# View Field Display placing table label on top of the description

Tags: views, entities, display-suite

So I have this table created with display suit and table group.

[image]

How am I going to make it look like this?

[image]

The label is already set to be above, but that doesn't seem to work.

I'm not really good in CSS nor Drupal. Consider me a newbie and willing to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Use list formatting with custom CSS.

Comment: I know this may sound stupid, but can you give me a little sample?

Comment: When you edit a view. Find  Format: Table | Settings . Click on "Table", select "HTML list".

Comment: The table I want to format is a table created from fields in a view and inside a page created by a view. 

It's a custom content type created by a view. 

I can't format it by going to Structure>content types>manage display.

Comment: Edit a view not a content type.

Comment: When I change it the the view table settings. The table on this page becomes a html list.(http://responsemap.iom.int/haiyan) and I'm suppose to format this content type page.(http://responsemap.iom.int/map/b663). Not the view page.